# Find number of rows needed to reach certain sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find the number of rows of a sorted table column I need in order for their sum to be a certain size. Here is my (very inefficient) attempt at the code:

```
DECLARE @CURNUM AS INT
DECLARE @CURSUM AS MONEY
SET @CURSUM=0.0
SET @CURNUM=1
WHILE @CURSUM<100000
BEGIN
     SET @CURNUM=@CURNUM+1
     SELECT @CURSUM = SUM(val1) FROM 
     (SELECT top (@CURNUM) val1 from table order by val1) a
END
print @CURNUM
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for a quicker implementation? I don't know how to select the ith row of a table, but if I did this would be much more efficient, that is my next methodology to try.

An unfortunate restriction: I can't create procedures or functions due to lack of database privelige.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a pre-2012 version:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (select sum(val1) from table t2 where t2.val1 <= t.val1) as cumesum
      from table t
     ) t
where cumesum <= 100000
```

This calculates the cumulative sum using a correlated subquery.  It then just counts the number less than or equal to the threshhold value.

In SQL Server 2012, the expression for `cumesum` is:

```
sum(val1) over (order by val1) as cumesum
```

Comment: I'm getting an arithmetic overflow, do you know what I can do to avoid it? I tried casting as bigint and that didn't help

Comment: This query calculates all cumulative sums.  Presumably, values larger than the threshold are causing the problem.  One idea would be to add a `top xxx` with an `order by`.  Or use a `where`.  Or, cast the values to `float`.  This will work, because you don't care about inaccuracies when the values get really big.